# Slow Queries when using MySQL as a Linked Server from SQL Server (ODBC Connection)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, odbc, linked-server

I'm seeing very poor query performance when running a stored routine on a MySQL linked server from a SQL Server. The query runs from the SQL Server

```
select * from OPENQUERY(COGNOS, 'call reporting.sr_vendor_location_report(''2011-06-13 00:00:00'',''2012-01-18 00:00:00'',1,''0,1'',28,''(All)'',''(All)'',1,''(All)'')')
```

takes 15 seconds but if I check the mysql query log or run it on the server directly, I see that it only takes 7 seconds.

I've read elsewhere that MySQL ODBC connections are slow but I haven't seen any solutions suggested. I tried setting up mysql-proxy (just running it with a redirection - no LUA scripts) but didn't see any improvement. I'm using the MySQL ODBC Connector 5.1 and running MySQL version 5.5 on the server.

I'd be enormously grateful for any ideas on what to try.

### UPDATE

It turns out that openquery runs each query twice on the mysql server, the first time presumably to get metadata. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: It turns out that SQL Server is running each query on the MySQL Server twice! Any ideas on why this would happen and how to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that using RPC instead of OPENQUERY solves the problem of SQL Server generating two queries.

e.g.

```
select * from OPENQUERY(COGNOS, 'call reporting.sr_vendor_location_report(''2011-06-13 00:00:00'',''2012-01-18 00:00:00'',1,''0,1'',28,''(All)'',''(All)'',1,''(All)'')')
```

becomes

```
exec('call ...') at COGNOS
```

Answer (score 0):

try to configure the provider to run out-of-process (right click on the provider and uncheck the allow in process box).

This is not exactly a setting related with performance, but I saw good performance gains in some cases with oracle, maybe it works with mysql too.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but no improvement, unfortunately

Comment: I rebooted the SQL Server entirely